# Using the article "the" before a first reference to a specific person and their profession

Tags: articles

Do I need to use "the" if I first reference a specific person and their profession? For instance: "In 1990, the historian John Johnson stated that [...]". I know i wouldn't use "the" if it was just the name and that I would use it if it was only the profession. What about the combination?

Comment: This is an unusual usage using 'the'. We would drop the article. _In 1990, historian John Johnson stated that [...]_. In news article you might also see this usage, _In 1990, a historian named John Johnson stated that [...]_.

Comment: We _could_ drop the article, but the version with _the_ seems perfectly idiomatic to me.

Comment: I agree with Kate, "the historian" is perfectly idiomatic. In fact, omitting the definite article sounds to me like journalese.